# Easysearch:autosuggest ReferenceError: Template is not defined

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, autosuggest, meteor-easy-search

I left to guess of what to do as after installing all the dependencies and easysearch:autosuggest in an application the app began to throw error. I'm on Meteor version-1.2.1. I'd thought it's lodash that's causingthe problem but after installing lodash the problem persists.

```
=> Meteor server restarted

Changes to your project's package version selections:

easysearch:autosuggest  added, version 2.0.10

W20170706-14:37:18.456(1)? (STDERR)
W20170706-14:37:18.462(1)? (STDERR) C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
W20170706-14:37:18.462(1)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20170706-14:37:18.462(1)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20170706-14:37:18.462(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20170706-14:37:18.465(1)? (STDERR)     at Package (lib/autosuggest.js:1:1)
W20170706-14:37:18.465(1)? (STDERR)     at C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\easysearch_autosuggest.js:101:4
W20170706-14:37:18.465(1)? (STDERR)     at C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\easysearch_autosuggest.js:108:3
W20170706-14:37:18.466(1)? (STDERR)     at C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:242:10
W20170706-14:37:18.472(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170706-14:37:18.47   Selecting package versions                -h (C:\Users\ken4ward\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\m
eteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:1                                              TDERR)     at C:\Programs\contract\crowducate-platform\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\
boot.js:137:5                                                       Selecting package versions                /
=> Exited with code: 8
```

meteor packages

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

less
accounts-password
useraccounts:bootstrap
alanning:roles
zimme:iron-router-active
cmather:handlebars-server@0.2.0
dburles:collection-helpers
reywood:publish-composite
mrt:moment
mrt:underscore-string-latest
matb33:collection-hooks
dburles:factory
anti:fake
cunneen:mailgun
iron:router@1.0.0
yasinuslu:blaze-meta
insecure
jeremy:selectize
reactive-var
rubaxa:sortable
cfs:filesystem
cfs:standard-packages
gadicohen:messageformat
browser-policy
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
babrahams:editable-text-wysiwyg-bootstrap-3
useraccounts:iron-routing
juliancwirko:s-alert
standard-minifiers
meteor-base
mobile-experience
mongo
blaze-html-templates
session
jquery
tracker
logging
reload
random
ejson
spacebars
check

themeteorchef:bert
ctjp:meteor-intl-tel-input
u2622:persistent-session
```

meteor version

```
accounts-base@1.2.2
accounts-password@1.1.4
alanning:roles@1.2.14
aldeed:autoform@5.7.1
aldeed:collection2@2.5.0
aldeed:simple-schema@1.4.0
amplify@1.0.0
anti:fake@0.4.1
autoupdate@1.2.4
babel-compiler@5.8.24_1
babel-runtime@0.1.4
babrahams:editable-text@0.8.6
babrahams:editable-text-wysiwyg@0.5.6
babrahams:editable-text-wysiwyg-bootstrap-3@0.5.6
base64@1.0.4
binary-heap@1.0.4
blaze@2.1.3
blaze-html-templates@1.0.1
blaze-tools@1.0.4
boilerplate-generator@1.0.4
browser-policy@1.0.5
browser-policy-common@1.0.4
browser-policy-content@1.0.6
browser-policy-framing@1.0.6
caching-compiler@1.0.0
caching-html-compiler@1.0.2
callback-hook@1.0.4
cfs:access-point@0.1.49
cfs:base-package@0.0.30
cfs:collection@0.5.5
cfs:collection-filters@0.2.4
cfs:data-man@0.0.6
cfs:file@0.1.17
cfs:filesystem@0.1.2
cfs:http-methods@0.0.30
cfs:http-publish@0.0.13
cfs:power-queue@0.9.11
cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9
cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4
cfs:standard-packages@0.5.9
cfs:storage-adapter@0.2.3
cfs:tempstore@0.1.5
cfs:upload-http@0.0.20
cfs:worker@0.1.4
check@1.1.0
cmather:handlebars-server@0.2.0
coffeescript@1.0.11
ctjp:meteor-intl-tel-input@3.7.1_2
cunneen:mailgun@0.9.1
dburles:collection-helpers@1.0.4
dburles:factory@0.3.10
dburles:mongo-collection-instances@0.3.4
ddp@1.2.2
ddp-client@1.2.1
ddp-common@1.2.2
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.0
ddp-server@1.2.2
deps@1.0.9
diff-sequence@1.0.1
djedi:sanitize-html@1.11.1
ecmascript@0.1.6
ecmascript-runtime@0.2.6
ejson@1.0.7
email@1.0.8
fastclick@1.0.7
fortawesome:fontawesome@4.4.0_1
fourseven:scss@3.3.3_3
gadicohen:headers@0.0.31
gadicohen:messageformat@0.0.52
geojson-utils@1.0.4
handlebars@1.0.4
hot-code-push@1.0.0
html-tools@1.0.5
htmljs@1.0.5
http@1.1.1
id-map@1.0.4
insecure@1.0.4
iron:controller@1.0.12
iron:core@1.0.11
iron:dynamic-template@1.0.12
iron:layout@1.0.12
iron:location@1.0.11
iron:middleware-stack@1.1.0
iron:router@1.0.12
iron:url@1.0.11
jeremy:selectize@0.12.1_4
jquery@1.11.4
juliancwirko:s-alert@3.1.2
lai:collection-extensions@0.1.4
launch-screen@1.0.4
less@2.5.1
livedata@1.0.15
localstorage@1.0.5
logging@1.0.8
matb33:collection-hooks@0.8.1
mdg:validation-error@0.1.0
meteor@1.1.10
meteor-base@1.0.1
meteorhacks:inject-initial@1.0.3
minifiers@1.1.7
minimongo@1.0.10
mobile-experience@1.0.1
mobile-status-bar@1.0.6
momentjs:moment@2.10.6
mongo@1.1.3
mongo-id@1.0.1
mongo-livedata@1.0.9
mrt:moment@2.8.1
mrt:underscore-string-latest@2.3.3
npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2
npm-mongo@1.4.39_1
observe-sequence@1.0.7
ordered-dict@1.0.4
promise@0.5.1
raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
random@1.0.5
rate-limit@1.0.0
reactive-dict@1.1.3
reactive-var@1.0.6
reload@1.1.4
retry@1.0.4
reywood:publish-composite@1.4.2
routepolicy@1.0.6
rubaxa:sortable@1.3.0
service-configuration@1.0.5
session@1.1.1
sha@1.0.4
softwarerero:accounts-t9n@1.1.6
spacebars@1.0.7
spacebars-compiler@1.0.7
srp@1.0.4
standard-minifiers@1.0.2
templating@1.1.5
templating-tools@1.0.0
themeteorchef:bert@2.1.0
tracker@1.0.9
u2622:persistent-session@0.4.4
ui@1.0.8
underscore@1.0.4
underscorestring:underscore.string@3.2.2
url@1.0.5
useraccounts:bootstrap@1.12.4
useraccounts:core@1.12.4
useraccounts:iron-routing@1.12.4
webapp@1.2.3
webapp-hashing@1.0.5
yasinuslu:blaze-meta@0.3.3
zimme:iron-router-active@1.0.4
```

These are the contents of the meteor version and packages.

Comment: Do you have `templating` installed? If so, which version? Posting the contents of your project's `meteor/versions` and `meteor/packages` files may be useful.

Comment: @MasterAM, these are the contents of the app Meteor version and packages. I have updated the content of the question.

Comment: Honestly, those versions are too old to try and trace the issue at the source level (repos were moved, API and code changed). It seems that that particular version of `autosuggest` depends on `templating` and expects it to export a global `Template` object, which the packaging system should make available to it on `lib/autosuggest.js`. I would try adding `templating` as a top-level dependency (i.e, installing `templating`). Other than that, I don't have any decent guess.